# QtWidget and QMenuBar are on the same line

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I have a problem with my menu bar. I'm using various QWidget in grid layout such as label, checkbox, listview etc. However, the widget on the first line is always on the same line as the menu bar (see figure -->
[image: figure]) I want the Hello label below the menu bar.

When I add the menuBar to GridLayout it would look like this [image]

Here is my code so far

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._initUI()

    def _initUI(self):
        self.resize(200, 70)
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icon.png"))
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)

        menuBar = QMenuBar(self)
        menuBar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 200, 21))
        menuFile = menuBar.addMenu("Configuration")
        menuBar.addMenu(menuFile)
        menuChangelog = menuBar.addMenu("Changelog")
        menuBar.addMenu(menuChangelog)

        metricslabel = QLabel("Hello", self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(metricslabel, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.show()
```

Comment: Why not just add the `QMenuBar` to the `QGridLayout` rather than trying to maname its geometry manually?  i.e. the menu bar goes on row 0 and the label on row 1 (with appropriate column spans).

Comment: @G.M. I have tried it but it didn't look like a menu bar... Because there is space around the menu bar

Comment: What do you mean by "there is space around the menu bar"? Also, why don't you use a standard QMainWindow?

Comment: @musicamante please see edit (second figure)

Comment: 1. [`QLayout.setContentsMargins()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins) and eventually [`QWidget.setContentsMargins()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setContentsMargins); 2. You didn't answer the question: why you're not using QMainWindow? 3. [`QLayout.setMenuBar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setMenuBar).

Answer (score 0):

For your window just use `void QMainWindow::setMenuBar(QMenuBar *menuBar)`.

It will be right under the title bar and won't be part of the window's layout